# What can cause gcc to partially compile C code?

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling a Python extension written in C which makes use of an external C extension (pycairo). When I compile and link against the external library, gcc produce a valid .so object. However, if I use the C API in the form of `PyCapsule` provided by pycairo, gcc partially assembles a function in one of my C sources. The function

```
static PyObject *
Canvas_show(Canvas* self) {
  struct timespec ts = {self->interval / 1e9, self->interval % (unsigned int) 1e9};
  int running;

  // Input events
  XSelectInput(self->display, self->win_id, ButtonPressMask | KeyPressMask);
  XMapWindow(self->display, self->win_id);

  PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("(O)", PycairoContext_FromContext(self->context, &PycairoContext_Type, NULL));
  for (running = 1; running;)
  {
    Canvas_on_draw(self, args, NULL);

    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
    cairo_surface_flush(self->surface);

    switch (cairo_check_event(self->surface, 0)) {
    case 0xff1b:   // Esc
    case -1:       // left mouse button
      running = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  Py_DECREF(args);
  cairo_destroy(self->context);
  cairo_surface_destroy(self->surface);
  XCloseDisplay(self->display);

  return Py_True;
}
```

is compiled by gcc into the following few instructions

```
00000000000010f0 <Canvas_show>:
    10f0:       53                      push   rbx
    10f1:       48 89 fb                mov    rbx,rdi
    10f4:       48 8b 77 38             mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x38]
    10f8:       48 8b 7f 30             mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x30]
    10fc:       ba 05 00 00 00          mov    edx,0x5
    1101:       e8 8a fb ff ff          call   c90 <XSelectInput@plt>
    1106:       48 8b 73 38             mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rbx+0x38]
    110a:       48 8b 7b 30             mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rbx+0x30]
    110e:       e8 bd fb ff ff          call   cd0 <XMapWindow@plt>
    1113:       48 8b 04 25 08 00 00    mov    rax,QWORD PTR ds:0x8
    111a:       00 
    111b:       0f 0b                   ud2    

Disassembly of section .fini:

0000000000001120 <_fini>:
    1120:       48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
    1124:       48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
    1128:       c3                      ret    
<EOF>
```

The code starting from 1113 seems already to be gibberish, and this is where I get a SIGSEGV when I run a test.

The same .so file is generated regardless of whether I use `distutils` or I manually compile the sources with

```
gcc -shared x11/x11module.c x11/canvas.c -o x11/x11.so -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6 -I/usr/include/cairo/ -lcairo -lX11
```

What can cause gcc to partially compile valid C code, without throwing errors?

Comment: A compiler generating "gibberish" is usually an indication of *undefined behavior* somewhere in your code

Comment: The problem only appears when I import "pycairo.h" to call the `import_cairo` macro. If I link against the compiled version of the library instead, the code works as expected. I would tend to conclude that, if there is some UB, it is probably brought into my code by pycairo.h.

Comment: Try compiling with the `-fsanitize=undefined` flag.

Comment: I am also suspicious of your timespec definition especially the cast to unsigned. The contents of timespec are not unsigned. So why the cast?

Comment: @ZanLynx the suggested flag produces better assembly code, thanks! As for the cast, I just assumed timespec used UINT without checking, as it made more sense to me.

Comment: The `-fsanitize` flags are for debugging only. They'll make the program very slow, but should report undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the cause is quite likely undefined behaviour. It turned out that the cause was a NULL pointer dereferencing done on a static variable that was never initialised.